# can't implement where clause in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t15_catalogue_line.T15_GROUP, 
sc_products.product_code,sc_products.unic,
  sc_products.name_ru,
  UPPER(TRIM(sc_products.brief_description_ru)) AS brief_description_ru,
  sc_products.suupplier,
  price.Price,
  sc_group_discounts.`action`,
  sc_group_discounts.procent,
  sc_products.productID,
  price.in_stock,
  price.supplier,
  t10_item.T10_ITEM,
  t10_item.T10_DESC,
  t10_item.T10_IMG,
  t10_item.T10_ITEM_GROUP,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD1,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD2,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD3,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD4,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD5,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD6,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD7,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD8,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD9,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD10,
  t10_item.T10_FIELD11,
  t14_item_fields.T14_ITEM_GROUP,
  t14_item_fields.T14_FIELD,
  t14_item_fields.T14_NAME,
  t14_item_fields.T14_UNIT,
  t14_item_fields.T14_SEARCH
FROM
  sc_products
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t15_catalogue_line ON (sc_products.unic = t15_catalogue_line.unic)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN price ON (sc_products.unic = price.unic)
  AND (sc_products.suupplier = price.postavchik)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_group_discounts ON (sc_products.item_group = sc_group_discounts.item_group)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t10_item ON (sc_products.product_code = t10_item.T10_ITEM)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t14_item_fields ON (t10_item.T10_ITEM_GROUP = t14_item_fields.T14_ITEM_GROUP)
WHERE
  t15_catalogue_line.T15_CARTYPE = '30416' AND 
  t15_catalogue_line.T15_GROUP = '546678'
    and sc_products.unic is not null and sc_products. unic!=''

GROUP BY
t15_catalogue_line.unic
```

The table is look like this 
t15_catalog_line:
t15_ITEM product code from supplier,
t15_cartype car model for wich needed parts
t15_group group of parts break system ets.
unic product code on a website. It is not unique so it does duplicate in other tables and there are could be seviral same product codes for different parts. THe problem is that if this setuation happens query returns first row that is mached disgarding where clause. How that could be fixed?

Comment: From first glance:

You are selecting DISTINCT group, and in the where clause you ask for a single group id. As far as I can tell, that should only return 1 result, which is group '546678'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `group by` clause completely.

MySQL allows non standard use of group by: if you use `group by`, but some non-aggregated columns are not listed in the `grouo by`, you get one row for each unique combination of the grouped by columns.

This is not what you want.

Comment: Still there are some problems 2 products are not asigned to the cartype